# User signup leads to IntegrityError

Tags: python, django

After a user signs up, the following IntegrityError is displayed:

```
IntegrityError at /users/signup
(1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 2")
```

Even though the user gets an error, he can log in regularly. The User gets created, along with the UserProfile.

Here is the /users/signup view that causes the error:

```
def signup(request):
  signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
  #goal = request.POST.get('goal')
  goal = None
  if signup_form.is_valid():
    username = signup_form.cleaned_data['username']
    email = signup_form.cleaned_data['email']
    password = signup_form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
  else:
    return render_to_response("authorize.html", {'signup_form': signup_form, 'goal': goal}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my /user/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from main.models import Goal

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  joined_goals = models.ManyToManyField(Goal, related_name="joined_goals")
  followingGoals = models.ManyToManyField(Goal, related_name="following_goals")

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username

  def get_goals(self):
    try:
      goals = Goal.objects.filter(user=self.user)
      return goals
    except Goal.DoesNotExist:
      return []

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I've dropped all of the tables in my MySQL database multiple times and run python manage.py syncdb, but I still get the same error everytime after creating a new user.

Edit: I do not get this error on my localhost, only on my remote host. I use sqlite on my localhost and mysql on my remote host.

Comment: Post the relevant view; also you can simplify `get_goals(self)` to simply `def get_goals(self): return Goal.objects.filter(user=self.user)` (`filter` returns an empty `QuerySet` if nothing matches, it won't raise `DoesNotExist`)

Comment: Don't you have any other signal handlers?

Comment: I added the relevant view. The only signal handler I have creates a new user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and suggest it could be your post_save signal being registered multiple times as a result of the models.py being loaded more than once. You aren't registering your signal in a safe manner. Maybe its trying to create the profile more than once rapidly on save() and getting the error.

Take a look at the docs on [Preventing Duplicate Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)

Try changing the last line to something like:

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, 
                    dispatch_uid="user_create_profile")
```

Having the dispatch uid will cause it only to be registered once, even if its called many times as a result of imports.

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason. Not sure why it was working on my local host but not my remote host, though.

Comment: @egidra: On your localhost I am assuming you were using the development server, and on the remote you were using some form of a production server?

Comment: @egidra: They load modules differently because they are 2 different servers. The development server is monitoring your files and doing code reloads, so I would assume you would get different behavior. Though I am not exactly sure at what point the problem would occur. Just that in the production server, the module was being imported more than once.