# Django IntegrityError on user signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-1.6

I am getting an error when I try to extend user profile using django-allauth

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: workerapp_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL
```

This is my models.py in my workerapp app of my django project where I am asking for two additional fields along with other signup information.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
  user    = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
  # The additional attributes we wish to include.
  website = models.URLField(blank=True)
  picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

  # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

My user is saving correctly which I can see in the admin, it's just the showing this error during the signup.

Comment: How are you creating the user?

Comment: I am using django-allauth app which takes care of user signup. It creates it own forms and templates, all I have to do is add  (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), in urls.py

Comment: Are you using a `post_save.connect` signal? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393232/user-signup-leads-to-integrityerror?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I tried with post_save.connect but it still shows me the same error. This is my new models.py http://dpaste.com/1545265/